# Virtual Host Is Not Working For Drupal In Apache

Tags: apache, virtualhost, drupal-views, clean-urls

I see the following *warning* when I install Drupal:

[image: Drupla warning - Clean URLs disabled]

I already activated a2enmod rewrite and make virtual host under /etc/apache2/site-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<Directory /home/rupinder/public_html/>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           allow from all
           Require all granted
         </Directory>
```

Still it is not working for drupal . Can anyone help me??

Comment: The error you are seeing (which should be embedded in your question and not externally linked to) would seem to imply the error is with Drupal, not the server config?

Comment: This problem is in drupal @MrWhite .Have you any solution??

Comment: There would seem to be a link in the warning message "Enable clean URLs" - what does that do?